# Parent Child Tables alternative

Tags: database, winforms, webforms, parent-child

Is there any alternative to creating two tables: parent and child to implement parent child form. I am working with a database where the Parent Table contains repeated feilds on the Child. This makes the concept annoying to me. I could code with it that way but its anoying to me. I want to redesign the database, possibly merge the tables to 1 and use views instead of tables. I need suggestion on a work around and possible the pros and cons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Add Parent Id in same Table to avoid using 2 tables.

ex.

category_id --------    category_name --------- parent_category_id

---

1 -------------------- CAT A --------------------- 0

2 -------------------- CAT CHILD A  ------------ 1

3 -------------------- CAT CHILD A 1  ---------- 1

4 -------------------- CHILD OF A  -------------- 2

Likewise. Hope this will help.